# Why would I write custom allocators for STL containers when I could just overwrite new and delete?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, c++20, allocator

I want to write a custom memory manager/allocator for learning. I'm tempted to have a master allocator that requests n bytes of ram from the heap (via new). This would be followed by several allocator... Adaptors? Each would interface with the master, requesting a block of memory to manage, these would be stack, linear, pool, slab allocators etc each managing allocations from their slice of the master pool allocator.

The problem I have is whether I should write custom allocator_traits to interface with these for the various STL containers; or if I should just ignore the adaptor idea and simply overload new and delete to use the custom pool allocator/manager, the master one.

What I'm interested in understanding is what tangible benefit I would gain from having separate allocators for STL containers? It seems like the default std::allocator calls new and delete as needed so if I overload those to instead request from my big custom memory pool, I'd get all the benefit without the kruft of custom std::allocator code.

Or is this a matter where certain types of allocator models, like using a stack allocator for a std::deque would work better than the default allocator? And if so, wouldn't the normal stl implementation already specialise the default allocator for the various container types, or otherwise be optimised in the calls to the default allocator?

If it matters at all, I'm using C++20 via GCC 10+

Comment: You may have different allocator systems that you might want to use for the containers (e.g.: an allocator for very short-lived objects, a different one for longer lived objects, maybe another one for very large objects, ...)

Comment: new and delete is for ALL the rest also while a special allocator can be set up for each single instance. So you can have several vectors with total different allocators. These optimization must not be a good choice for all memory allocations in the rest of your prog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the two questions in-order:

**Should I write custom allocator_traits to interface my allocators for the various STL containers?**

Yes, for easy manipulations. Pretty soon in the implementation, situations such as controlling memory overlaps would arise. For example, while stress-testing the implementation at full capacity of individual allocators and figuring out an algorithm for re-allocation. In this regard, you would need to specialize the `allocator_traits` class for the allocators rather than implement its `member types` from scratch using `new` and `delete` operators.

The reason allocator_traits is used is because it facilitates easy handling of *certain rules that need to be respected*. Such rules occur all across memory management. [Refer [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AllocatorAwareContainer) for three such rules during allocator construction.]

**What tangible benefit I would gain from having separate allocators for STL containers?**

Absolute control of how the master allocator assigns, re-assigns, copies, moves, and destructs memory (with added controls over quantifying/enhancing performance). Pretty cool, isn't it! If the default std allocator is used, you would loose this control and rely on a (albeit very good) default implementation of memory management.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace the global allocator, including in every library you are using, you don't have to use `std::allocator`.

std allocators let you do things like create temporary allocation pools.  Suppose you have some data structures you can guarantee will not outlive a certain scope, and you know that (whatever is allocated) 90%+ will remain allocated to the end of the scope.

A relatively simple std allocator could hand outmemory, never recycle it, and clean it up at the end of the scope much faster than any global `new` or `delete` operator could.

Whenever you have special knowledge of the contents and lifetime patterns of a container, you could hand-tune an allocator for that specific container.  The standard allocator cannot.  Sometimes when you are willing to make compromises that the std containers are not, you can patch their behavior with a custom allocator.

`std::deque` cannot efficiently use a stack allocator, because it cannot presume you'll mainly use it as a stack.  You might use it mainly a queue.  A stack allocator when you use it mainly as a queue would be a disaster; but if you used it 90%+ as a stack, a stack allocator could be much faster at the cost of modest memory overhead (and if 99%+, a stack allocator that handles the exceptional case and cleans up the non-stack based operations).

Finally, allocators can permit you to distinguish between kinds of containers.  You might want the memory for your document (persistent) state to be allocated in one region of memory, and your "scratch" non-persistent data to be allocated elsewhere.

And yes, using a std allocator is something you should consider not doing.  Optimization is fungible, and tweaking low level memory allocation is something you can work on after you have made the rest of the system more efficient and functional.  Only when you have something that works, isn't fast enough, and you have identified new/delete as a fundamental bottle neck you can't design around should you say "ok, time to replace allocation!"

Answer (score 1):

Use Case: Security Software needs to `shred` memory on delete, 'cause it cannot afford to let sensitive data remain somewhere in the physical RAM, optionally accessible by later instantiated processes. The delete operators of standard run-times won't do this expensive operation. Overwriting the heap operators might lead to linker problems with libraries depending on the runtime versions of those.